# Prepare access to many DB tables for a possible later usage with spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am doing my first steps with Spark and looking currently into ways to Import some data from a database via a JDBC driver.
My plan is that I prepare  the access for many tables from the 
DB for a possible later usage from another team with pure SparkSQL commands.
So they can focus on the data and have no contact with the code anymore.

My connection to the DB is working and I found so far two working ways to get some data.

Way 1:

```
sqlContext.read.jdbc(url,"tab3",myProp).registerTempTable("tab3")
```

Way 2:

```
case class RowClass_TEST (COL1:String, COL2:String)
val myRDD_TEST= new JdbcRDD(sc,() => DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,pw), "select * from TEST where ? < ?",  0,1,1,row => RowClass_TEST(row.getString("COL1"),row.getString("COL2")) myRDD_TEST.toDF().registerTempTable("TEST")
```

But both ways have some bad effects,

Way 1 is not so fast if you have to prepare a higher amount of tables that are not used later.
(I trace 5 jdbc commandos during the execution of the example  ( create connection, login, settings, query for header, terminate connection) )

Way 2 works very fast, but the `case class` from Scala hast a heavy limitation.
You can only setup 22 values with this kind of class.

So is there an easy solution to setup way 2 without a `case class`?
I want to access some DB tables with more than 22 columns.

I tried already to get it working ,but my Scala know-how is not good enough yet.

Comment: _You can only setup 22 values with this kind of class_ - it is not true for a long time now.

Comment: Ah , that sounds good.  I am using a Zeppelin Web GUI as a frontend for my tests and got an error message ( just a number) from my to big `case class`.  Was the border removed with a newer Scala version?

Comment: 2.11 - https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7296. There are still some 22 limits present though.

Comment: Update:  it was .... Version  2.11.1  release in May 2014

Comment: [link](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html#building-for-scala-211)    ==>   Spark does not yet support its JDBC component for Scala 2.11.

Comment: It does in practice since 1.5 or 1.6 (I don't remember which one) and as far as I remember it was never about jdbc reader.

Answer (score 1):

You can write something like this:

```
sqlContext.load("jdbc",
      Map(
         "url" -> "jdbc:mysql://dbConnectionString",
         "dbtable" ->
            "(SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE someField > 10 ) AS a"
         )
   ).registerTempTable("tmp_table")
```

Comment: Thanks for your post.
I just tested this code and it looks like it is an older syntax of the above way 1.
It behaves in exact the same way.  I see also the 5 jdbc commandos in wireshark.
But I learned also something from it. The version with the sub command can be helpful for my next steps :D

Comment: That's the catch, with that subquery you can minimise data volume on which you will work.

Comment: It isn't the answer for my problem, but you are right.
This is a very valuable hint, because it can speedup the access a lot with the right filter.
I tested it just with a `sqlContext.read.jdbc()` function and it is working there as well.